# method getCheckedRadioButtonId must be called from the UI thread Android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I write bellow code in `AsyncTask` but get me error and say :

*method getCheckedRadioButtonId must be called from the UI thread**

```
 new AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>(){

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            long result = 0;
            long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
   HERE---->switch (StartActivity.this.RadioType.getCheckedRadioButtonId()){
                case R.id.radioFibJR:
                    result = FibLib.fibJR(n);
                    break;
                case R.id.radioFibJI:
                    result = FibLib.fibJI(n);
                    break;
                case R.id.radioFibNR:
                    result = FibLib.fibNR(n);
                    break;
                case R.id.radioFibNI:
                    result = FibLib.fibNI(n);
                    break;
            }
            t = System.currentTimeMillis() - t;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
        }
    }.execute();
```

Comment: do it like DroidHacker said, but if You must get the state necessarily in doInBackground(for whatever reason), You can use runOnUiThread()

Comment: Ok.Thanks .@Opiatefuchs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put that code outside of the AsyncTask. Thats the trick. cheers :)

```
 int id=StartActivity.this.RadioType.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
 new AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>(){

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            long result = 0;
            long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
             switch (id){
                case R.id.radioFibJR:
                    result = FibLib.fibJR(n);
                    break;
                case R.id.radioFibJI:
                    result = FibLib.fibJI(n);
                    break;
                case R.id.radioFibNR:
                    result = FibLib.fibNR(n);
                    break;
                case R.id.radioFibNI:
                    result = FibLib.fibNI(n);
                    break;
            }
            t = System.currentTimeMillis() - t;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
        }
    }.execute();
```